# Compensated Poisson Random Measures and Levy Processes

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, levy-processes, point-processes

[image: Q8.1]

This is a proposition from my lecture notes (no proof is given -- it's left as an exercise). The section on Poisson random measures starts on page 43 of these [lecture notes](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Lectures/ap.pdf). At this point in the course, we hadn't got to Lévy processes -- they're chapter nine -- but I now known that "cadlag with stationary, independent increments" means "Lévy" (basically); however, of course, I don't want to use general Lévy process results. There is a very similar claim in Theorem 8.2.1. I expect to have a proof reasonably similar to this, but I haven't been able to get anywhere. In the proof of Theorem 8.2.1, it claims a certain form of the Poisson random measure $M$. I don't 100% see why this is allowed, and thus can't see if I can apply it in this situation. (I mean, I could just assume that it still works, pretend it's applied maths and hope for the best!)

I don't really have a very good understanding about PRMs in general. For example, I'm really not sure how to take a condition expectation when the random thing is a measure. I mean, I could just push through some definitions, like the proof of T8.2.1, but I'd be interested in getting a better understanding about them in general. If anyone could offer me some insight/intuition into what they actually *are*, then that would be great!

---

Also, if you've seen my questions before, then you'll have likely seen this disclaimer before. *Please do not just post full solutions!* I want to learn maths and, I believe, the best way to do that is to work out as much of the question as I can myself! A small hint to start with would be appreciated; if I'm still stuck, then I'll ask for a larger hint. Thank you!

Comment: In case you're interested about (Poisson) random measure, I would recommend the textbook "Probability and Stochastics" by Cinlar - it is covered in great detail there (introduced at the end of chapter 1, and then used in detail in chapter 6, in a similar way to your professor's notes).